# Authenticate against samba share

Tags: samba, pam

I tend to a number of computers running Ubuntu Linux. I want a central service to authenticate console users against. All user files (home) should be in one location. I am aware there are numerous sensible solutions to this, including (but not limited to) a file-server exporting shares via NFS and LDAP or Kerberos or even a Microsoft Active Directory. However, due to budget cuts, I am not granted any of those. Only thing I do have is a file-server with a samba share. On a single share, each user has a destinct directory only writable to them. Can I authenticate a console user against a samba share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Considerations

There is different parts to this:

1. The authentication itself ("may this user use the computer?").
2. The account data including user information, ID mapping, group membership,… (the data of e.g. `getent passwd`).

##### Authentication

Checking credentials (user and password) against a samba share is relatively easy. You can use `smbclient`:

```
smbclient --user="$PAM_USER" --password="$password" --directory "$PAM_USER" --command="quit" "\\\\fileserver.example.com\\homes"
```

This command will succeed if the credentials are correct and fail if the server rejects them. You can use it with [pam_exec](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_exec). pam_exec will set `$PAM_USER` and also helps with obtaining `$password`. See the full example at the end of this answer. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640994/linux-custom-authentication-with-pam-exec) question has a similar intent.

Adding this to the PAM [auth](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/User-Authentication-HOWTO/x115.html) stage will handle the authentication, but on its own will not make the login work.

##### Account

In order to actually use the system, the user must be known to the system. This is handled by the Name Service Switch (nss). I am not aware of any samba-specific module, though. Also, we do not really need one. Since we already know that a user provided credentials which have been validated by the samba server, we can simply create a local user on the fly and give it with the very same password. Also, I want to add the user to a special goup `sambahome` so I can easily differentiate between ordinary local users (such as root) and users with their home on the share.

```
adduser "$PAM_USER" --quiet --gecos "" --home "/home/$PAM_USER" --no-create-home --add_extra_groups --disabled-password &&
echo "$PAM_USER:$passwd" | chpasswd &&
adduser "$PAM_USER" "sambahome"
```

##### Storage

Since the user's home directory resides on a samba share, we can employ [pam_mount](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/pam_mount) to mount the share automatically during logon.

#### Implementation

##### Authentication

This is my default `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`, expanded by some lines:

```
auth    [success=3 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok
auth    optional    pam_exec.so expose_authtok /usr/local/sbin/pam-addsmbuser
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
auth    required            pam_permit.so

auth    [success=ok default=1] pam_succeed_if.so quiet_fail user ingroup sambahome
auth    optional    pam_mount.so
```

The first line (with `pam_unix`) checks the credentials for a local user.
On success, the next 3 lines are skipped and `pam_permit` takes effect.
In case there is no local user, the second line will be considered. `pam_exec` will execute `pam-addsmbuser` which will create a new local user. Then `pam_unix` is queried again (in the third line).

In either case, `pam_mount` is executed, but only if the user actually has their home on the samba share. Guarding this with `pam_succeed_if` is optional, but keeps auth logs clean.

##### Account

In whole, `/usr/local/sbin/pam-addsmbuser` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
read password
if smbclient --workgroup="AD.FH-WEDEL.DE" --user="$PAM_USER" --password="$password" --directory "$PAM_USER" --command="quit" "\\\\fs1.ad.fh-wedel.de\\tux-homes"
then
    adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" --home "/home/ad/$PAM_USER" --no-create-home --quiet --add_extra_groups "$PAM_USER" &&
    echo "$PAM_USER:$password" | chpasswd &&
    adduser "$PAM_USER" "sambahome"
fi
```

Please note that `$PAM_USER` is an environment variable whereas `$password` is read from standard input.

##### Storage

The relevant lines in `/etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml`:

```
<volume fstype="cifs" server="fileserver.example.com" path="homes/%(USER)" mountpoint="/home/%(USER)" options="uid=%(USER),gid=%(USERGID),dir_mode=0700,file_mode=0700,nosuid,nodev,mfsymlinks" />
<mkmountpoint enable="1" remove="true" />
```

You might need to tweak the options at the end according to your needs. I have mixed feelings about `mfsymlinks`.

##### Session

In order to work, `pam_mount` also must be present in `/etc/pam.d/common-session`:

```
session [success=ok default=1] pam_succeed_if.so quiet_fail user ingroup sambahome
session optional    pam_mount.so
```

#### Results

I have been using this setup for months. So far it looks sufficiently reliable.

#### Caveats

As far as I can tell, this method of checking credentials only works for username and password. Password-less methods such as public-key authentication via SSH probably will not work. I did not check.

This system will not handle password changes gracefully. If the local password is changed, authentication will succeed via `pam_unix`, but the samba server will reject the password and `pam_mount` will fail. Similar problems arise with a server-side password change. This can probably be worked around with more intricatre scripts.

Local UIDs will not be the same across the systems. I do not see any problem with that, though.